# How to give MSSQL$SQL2016 permissions to write to a folder

Tags: sql-server, permissions, windows-10-desktop

Morning,

I have hit a brick wall and I need pointing in the right direction.
What I am trying to do is give my SQL Server instance permission to create the MDB / LDB files in a directory on a new hard drive I have installed on my local machine, without using Everyone.

When I try to create a new database in the folder (through management studio) I get the following error:

```
===================================

Create failed for Database 'TestDatabase1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com /fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=13.0.16106.4+((SSMS_Rel_16_5).170125-2137)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.ApplyChanges(Control marshallingControl)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabase.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean retry)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext, Boolean executeForAlter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImplFinish(StringCollection createQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()

===================================

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'D:\MSSQL\Data\TestDatabase1.mdf'.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.4224&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: my_machine\SQL2016
Error Number: 5123
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)
```

The SQL Server instance  is logging on using "NT Service\MSSQL$2016".
I have checked the original data folder and MSSQL$2016 has permissions to read and write.

I've had a look at these posts:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/08/25/sql-server-fix-create-file-encountered-operating-system-error-5-access-is-denied/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017

https://serverfault.com/questions/507496/sql-server-2012-with-account-nt-service-mssqlserver-access-is-denied-in-domain

http://documentation.sqlserverbooster.com/en/1_1_2/SQLServerBoosterDocumentation.html?AddingreadwritepermissionstoNTSe.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-do-i-give-file-system-access-to-sql-servers-sqlserveragent-virtual-account

I have also tried adding the following to the folder by right clicking on the folder->properties->Security, none of which have worked

```
NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2016
[NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2016]
[NT Service]\MSSQL$SQL2016
[NT Service]\[MSSQL$SQL2016]
MSSQL$SQL2016
```

When I click on the Check Names it cannot find it.

If it makes any difference this is on a Windows 10 PC on a domain.

I have missed something obvious but I am not sure what it is.  If you could point me at a document, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Might be good to try to restart the SQL services after applying the security settings?

Comment: Sorry misread that you could not find the user. Make sure you select the correct Location (local, not AD tree) before performing the search.

Comment: Thank you @kcotman . I thought I had tried that, but it would appear not, that seems to have cured it.

Comment: glad it works! Cheers

Answer (score 17):

At my machine the solution was assigning user:

`NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2016` (instead of `MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2016`)

in the dialog box where you manage access rights to concrete directory.

Comment: Do not forget the UPPER CASING, otherwise it wont find the user. It happened to me and it took me a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

On my side, I followed this documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15

In a nutshell, I had to search for the user **NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER**

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`NT Service\MSSQL$SQL2016`

Give full permission

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I tried to add the user to the folder, the list did not contained my user. So I copied the user from sql configuration and then paste it in the security settings for the folder.